# proc_terminate() does not terminate process even after lots of time

Tags: php, c++

I open a process using `proc_open()`, then `usleep()` for some time and after that check status of the process. If the process is still running then I `proc_terminate()` it.

The problem is when I use `proc_terminate()` the script continues without waiting for process to terminate (which is normal), ***but the process is not terminated even after lots of time.***

The process is an `.exe` file which first prints `hello` to **stdout**, then enters an infinite loop.

My PHP script :

```
<pre>
<?php

$descriptorspec = array(
    1 => array('pipe', 'w')
    );
$process = proc_open("C:/wamp/www/my-project/run.exe", $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    usleep(2.5*1000000); // wait 2.5 secs

    $status = proc_get_status($process);
    if ($status['running'] == true) {
        proc_terminate($process);
        echo "Terminated\n";
    } else {
        echo "Exited in time\n";
        echo "EXIT CODE : {$status['exitcode']}\n";
        echo "OUTPUT :\n";

        while (!feof($pipes[1]))
            echo fgets($pipes[1]);

        fclose($pipes[1]);
        proc_close($process);
    }
}

?>
</pre>
```

I compile this C++ file and get the `.exe` :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "hello";
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Does anybody know why this happens? :(

Answer (score 2):

`proc_terminate()` doesn't work well on Windows.

A good workaround is to call the `taskkill` command.

```
function kill($process) {
    if (strncasecmp(PHP_OS, 'WIN', 3) == 0) {
        $status = proc_get_status($process);
        return exec('taskkill /F /T /PID '.$status['pid']);
    } else {
        return proc_terminate($process);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`proc_terminate` doesn't actually terminate a process, it sends a `SIGTERM` signal to the process asking it to terminate itself.

I think that the problem is that your test executable is not listening for the `SIGTERM` signal, so it is just ignored.

On POSIX systems, you can use the second parameter to send a `SIGKILL`, which will essentially ask the OS to terminate the process, so that might work better.  On Windows, I don't know what, if anything, this would do.

But the process should be handling signals anyway.  You can easily add a signal handler to your exe for testing:

```
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
 
void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    cout << "received SIGTERM\n";
    exit(0);
}
 
int main()
{
    // Install a signal handler
    std::signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);
    
    cout << "starting\n";

    while (1)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    return 0;
}
```

Note the addition of `sleep_for` also, so that the exe doesn't take 100% of the CPU.

There is also a discussion in the comments [here](https://www.php.net/proc_terminate) about using `posix_kill()` to kill a process and its children, if the above does not work for you.